# Unable to read a JSON File

Tags: java, json, eclipse, io, gson

Please have a look at the following code

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader( new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s3Object.getObjectContent())) );
reader.beginArray();
int gsonVal = 0;
 while (reader.hasNext() && gsonVal < 3) {
    JsonParser  _parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement jsonElement =  _parser.parse(reader);
    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
    //Do something

    System.out.println(jsonObject.get("title"));}
```

I am trying to read a HUGE Json file using `GSON`. The format of the JSON file is as below

```
[
    {
        "hash_index": "00102x05h06l0aj0dw",
        "body": "Who's signing up for Obamacare?",
        "_type": "ArticleItem",
        "title": "Who's signing up for Obamacare? - Jan. 13, 2014",
        "source": "money.cnn.com",
        "primary_key": 0,
        "last_crawl_date": "2014-01-14",
        "url": "http://money.cnn.com/2014/01/13/news/economy/obamacare-enrollment/index.html"
    },
    {
        "hash_index": "00102x05h06l0aj0dw0iz0kn0l@0t#0",
        "body": "Who's signing up for Obamacare?",
        "_type": "ArticleItem",
        "title": "Who's signing up for Obamacare? - Jan. 13, 2014",
        "source": "money.cnn.com",
        "primary_key": 1,
        "last_crawl_date": "2014-01-14",
        "url": "http://money.cnn.com/2014/01/13/news/economy/obamacare-enrollment/index.html"
    }
]
```

When I run my code, I get the folling error.

```
java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1377)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:538)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:332)
at HashCreator.createHash(HashCreator.java:223)
at HashCreator.<init>(HashCreator.java:65)
at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Line 223 is - `reader.beginArray();`

This is the first time I am using this `GSON` and tha is because my JSON file is too big and cannot be loaded at once due to `OutOfMemoryException`. So, what Can I do with this error?

Comment: looks like there is no input at all.